# Query that only show 1 result

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I'm looking for a query that will fill a listbox but show one result of the same name. Let me explain better with an example. So say I have jack, john and mark as analysts in my table. jack is belongs to 6 records, john 2 and mark 2. I don't want jack to show up 6 times in my list box, only once.

So here is the code I'm using that brings up jack 6 times:

```
cmbAllGroups.RowSource = "Select Analyst from tblActionLog';"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a group by statement or a distinct statement.

```
cmbAllGroups.RowSource = "select Analyst from tblActionLog group by Analyst';"
```

or

```
cmbAllGroups.RowSource = "select distinct Analyst from tblActionLog';"
```

Answer (score 3):

try this instead

```
SELECT DISTINCT Analyst FROM tblActionLog
```